# ng-if JSON value not empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

try to show items in ng-repeat, only if value of some key not empty.

This is code:

```
<a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy:'match_time'" ng-if="e.match_timer !== NaN && e.match_status !== 'FT'">
```

e.match_timer looks like:

```
{
match_timer: ""
}
```

Comment: try using `ng-if="e.match_timer !==''"`

Comment: thanks, it works! I tried "" but it not working

Comment: if you are using double quotes(") then you should use single quotes for directive like `ng-if='e.match_timer !==""'` or to escape double quotes(") you can use slash (\\)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `ng-if` you can write your condition like this

```
<a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy:'match_time'" ng-if="e.match_timer !== '' && e.match_status !== 'FT'">
```

This way it will display only those elements which are non-empty for `e.match_timer` and has other value then FT

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the length of the string.

```
e.match_timer.length > 0 or e.match_timer > 0 if it is number.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ng-if` you should use a [ng-filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter), like this

*Html:*

```
<a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy:'match_time' | filter:filterExpression">{{e.match_timer}}</a>
```

*JS:*

```
myApp.filter('filterExpression', function() {
  return function (e) {
    return typeof (e.match_timer) === 'string' && e.match_status !== 'FT'
  };
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9381/